# SSIS conversion to Project Deployment & Convert Deployment Model

Tags: sql-server, deployment, ssis

I have 3 2008-style SSIS packages that I think I've done a pretty good job upgrading to the 2016 tooling.  I've migrated to Project Deployment at the top level and I'm using project params - it all seems like a big improvement.

My first problem is that when I deploy to the server, it seems to succeed, but the Integration Services explorer mode in SSMS shows no packages in the place I expect to see them.  The new folder is there but there's nothing in it.  I was able to use 7zip to uncompress the .ispac file in the /bin folder which is being deployed and it does indeed contain the .dtsx files that I expect to see.

When I deploy, the deployment wizard lists the .ispac file Path under Source section, but not the individual packages.  That's probably fine but I'll mention it in case I should see the individual packages listed.

I also notice that there's an option to "Convert Deployment Model" under the Visual Studio project's SSIS Packages section - that's separate from the "Convert to Package/Project Deployment" at the project-level.  It's also separate from the "Upgrade All Packages" option that has already been done and for which there are no remaining upgradable packages.

When I run the "Convert Deployment Model" wizard and try to "Next" past the screen where the packages are listed as "Not loaded" Status, I get an error that "One or more selected packages are not ready" an an Error status on all packages with the message that `The variable "$Project::ServerB" was not found in the Variables collection. The variable might not exist in the correct scope.`

`@[$Project::ServerB]` is indeed a variable in all of the packages.  And in at least one of the xml content of the package files I can see it listed in just the one place.  In the editor (the Expression field of the SQL Connection Manager) where we use the variable this project parameter evaluates to the configured value just fine.

What is this "Convert Deployment Model" option anyway, separate from the "Convert to Package/Project Deployment" option?  Are they the same, and the one on the "SSIS Package" folder just failing to validate the conversion (back to Package Deployment) because there are project parameters that the resulting Package Deployment mode doesn't support, hence the error?

And most importantly, why aren't my packages actually getting deployed?  Is this deployment model thing just a red herring at this point?  What should I be seeing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking in the wrong spot.  In SSMS, I see them under the Database Engine side of the Object Explorer, but not under the Integration Services side.  Integration Services had a folder that might have been carried over from the old deployments and seems no longer necessary.  Under the database there is a new "Integration Services Catalogs" folder that now shows the projects along with the expected deployed packages.

I guess the "Convert Deployment Model" was just a distraction.